# mysql master master replication out of sync

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have 2 server set on mysql master master replication. we can call it as good server and bad server.

Good server has all the latest data. Once of table in the bad server is not in sync and have old data. How can I sync the new data into that table? Can i dump the table from the good server and then restore it to bad server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and resynchronise your databases manually but it's usually much easier to use tools designed for this purpose. Check out these two utilities and pick the one the best fits your situation:

MySQL provides [mysqlrplsync](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqlrplsync.html) as part of the Database Utilities package.

Percona offers [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) as part of their Toolkit.